# Pointer to function with dereferencing operator(*) in C

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I get little confused with pointer to function.

Let’s say

```
int func (int parameter){
    return parameter + 5;
}
int (* pfunction)(int) = func;

pfunction(5); //this will return 10
```

But I wonder what it means without parantheses. Like this.

```
pfunction

*pfunction
```

I know the difference between these two in case of pointer to int, float, double ... but I have no clue what these two mean when it comes to ***pointer to function***.

Could you explain this?

Comment: "what it means without parentheses." --> post how you might use this in code.  `pfunction`
, `*pfunction` by themselves means little.

Comment: An `int` is just a value, stored in memory. An `int*` is a pointer to that piece of memory. A function pointer is a pointer to where a function in the memory starts (where the machine code of that function begins). The function itself is the ordered set of instructions.

Comment: The TL;DR is that the forms are equivalent when it comes to functions, since a function identifier always "decays" into a function pointer when used in an expression. For details check the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pfunction` means function pointer and it holds the reference to the function

`*pfunction` dereferenced function pointer will give the same reference to the function

`&pfunction` address of the `pfunction` pointer

when calling function pointers both forms are correct: `pfunction(5) and (*pfunction)(5)`

Example:

```
int  func (int parameter){
    return parameter + 5;
}
int main(void)
{
    int (*pfunction)(int) = func;

    printf("%d\n", pfunction(5)); //this will return 10
    printf("%d\n", (*pfunction)(5)); //this will return 10

    printf("pfunction \t%p\n", (void *)pfunction);
    printf("*pfunction \t%p\n", (void *)*pfunction);
    printf("&pfunction \t%p\n", (void *)&pfunction);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)func);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)main);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7eq581